# Why does this SQLAlchemy query returning illogical values that was not requested?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

```
    posts_query = (db.session.query(Post).
                   join(PostOption,PostOption.post_id == post_obj.id).
                   filter(and_(PostOption.key == "name",
                               PostOption.val == 'a')).
                   filter(Post.place_id == post_obj.place_id)
                   )

    print map(lambda x:get_post_values(x),posts_query.all())
```

returns

```
[{u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'a'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}, {u'name': u'b'}]
```

Comment: OT: Please don't use lambda x: get_post_values(x) where get_post_values would suffice.

Comment: oops, you are absolutely right. late night coding and its perils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it's the join, it appears you're joining Post to PostOptions on PostOption.post_id = some literal value.  Think you mean something like this:

```
posts_query = (db.session.query(Post).
  join(PostOption, PostOption.post_id == Post.id).
  filter(and_(PostOption.key == "name", PostOption.val == 'a')).
  filter(Post.place_id == post_obj.place_id).
  filter(Post.id == post_obj.id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here:

Include the place_id clause inside the and_:

```
posts_query = (db.session.query(Post).
           join(PostOption,PostOption.post_id == post_obj.id).
           filter(and_(PostOption.key == "name",
                       PostOption.val == 'a',
                       Post.place_id == post_obj.place_id))
           )
```

Comment: tried it, doesn't work :( also, this fix don't make logical sense either. the resulting sql query is the same.